# BeautifulSoupにてXML中のnameタグの中身を取得する方法

Tags: python, python3, xml, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup4、Python 3.6を使用しています。
パーサーはlxml-xmlです。
以下のようなXMLをパースして、`entry.name.string`を取得しようとすると、エラーとなります。
`<entry><name>Foo</name><value>80</value></entry>`
BeautifulSoupで使用するタグ名が格納された「name」属性とかぶってしまったみたいです。
これ以外に子要素を取得する方法はありませんでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

このような場合は、`entry.find("name").string`と、find関数を使うとうまくいきます。